# ERROR SHOWING IN ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, gradle

Error:Execution failed for task `:app:processDebugGoogleServices`. > No matching client found for package name `com.subham.decor`

Comment: please add details

Comment: which type of details

Comment: add build.gradle file

Comment: Make sure your pakage name in mainifests file same as your gradle's applicationId.

Comment: I am new at this would you plz tell how to add

Comment: package name is same as appication id in manifest file

Comment: @Subhamgcet115 in your project does have google-services.json file?

Comment: yes @PratikTank

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in the dependencies of the project-level `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {

classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: @Subhamgcet115 are you sure ? you are adding that line in project-level `build.gradle`

Comment: post your app-level `build.gradle` in your question

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have pasted your google-services.json file in project's app folder. Also check your package name inside the json file is correct(com.subham.decor).

Comment: "package_name": "com.decor.android" this is written in pckage name

Comment: json file is pasted checked in app module

Comment: Your package name is "com.subham.decor" right? Then what is "com.decor.android"?

Comment: while connection through fire base its was written as a hint that com.project name.android so i had written in that fashion only com.decor(my project name).android

Comment: No..that's wrong. Write your actual package name only . Like, "package_name" : "com.subham.decor"

Comment: problem solved i was doing wrong in package name they were not similar

Answer (score 0):

Check your package name on your google-services.json

> Example

```
"client_info": {
"mobilesdk_app_id": "1:6596814400689:android:65d6f25f5006145",
"android_client_info": {
  "package_name": "com.my.app.package.name"
}
```

Comment: "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:28619055192:android:75a1f5c20b805fec",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.decor.android"
it is written in this fashion

Comment: @Subhamgcet115 either change the package name in build.gradle or download a other json by making different project in console but make sure package name must be similar

Comment: @Subhamgcet115 better to download new json file from console and make sure you have same package name as on manifest file in create project over console.

Comment: problem solved i was doing wrong in package name they were not similar

Comment: @Subhamgcet115 happy to help .if you like you can accept the answer